# Visual Studio Lightswitch Beta2

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, rad, visual-studio-lightswitch

What are your **experiences** with **Beta2 of Visual Lightswitch**? Can it already be used for real life projects? Does anybody know, when the final (RTM) version  will be out?
I am very intersting in using Lightswitch in the future for **RAD**, but I am a litte bit self-conscious, if the tool is flexible enough for my **dividual requirements** and if a Lightswitch solution can be **extended with own code** !? Can it be mixed with "normal" Silverlight?

Comment: I asked similar questions specifically regarding Blend (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457469/lightswitch-and-expression-blend-will-they-work-together). The answers shed some light on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am currently in production with a Lightswitch application connected to SQL Server 2008 via IIS.  I am using it to create basic stuff for now like orders, invoices.  My experience so far is very good considering Beta 2.  Small bugs on slower computers but nothing to stop continuing.  It will take you longer to build a nice database than to build the front-end application in LS.  If you do your db design right, then the rest is easy and flawless.  You can extend alot with Lightswitch like using custom Silverlight controls so basically sky is the limit if you know Silverlight programming.  This is what I like, I know I can build on top with future options for my app like bing maps, upload pictures or documents.
For me, this is the perfect tool since I am not a super programmer.  Once your data is in SQL, then the fun begins, you will be able to create reports via Reporting Services.  If you the want to go even further, then create some SSIS`s to automate email report notifications, etc... which is what I am planning to do.

Basically, Lightswitch is driving me crazy because I can now build an app 10 times faster than if I would have to program it in Silverlight.

I don't know the release date.

Francis

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 will be launched on July 26, 2011.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch